# Disable irb autocomplete

Tags: ruby, irb

The latest version of irb introduced an autocomplete that is quite buggy and I don't generally like to be distracted by an autocomplete, any idea how I can disable it?

[image]

Related question: [How to disable Pry autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72232319/how-to-disable-pry-autocomplete/72232397#72232397)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try putting this in your [`~/.irbrc`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/IRB.html)

```
IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

Comment: Perfect, it works, thanks a lot

Comment: @Dorian could you accept my answer?

Comment: sorry just did, thanks again for the answer, I also added `IRB.conf[:ECHO_ON_ASSIGNMENT] = true`

Comment: I did not have an `~/.irbrc` file so I created it and put `IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false` and `require "irb/completion"` in it, saved and restarted the terminal but it is still auto suggesting, can you tell me what I am missing.

Comment: something recently happened, pasting code into the console is triggering auto complete. This helps

Comment: You can also put the `.irbrc` file in your repo directory and it will work for all Users and in Production/Staging/etc.

Comment: @Ricky did you create it as a file or directory? In my case I just created it as a file in the home directory and add  `IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false` and it works.

Comment: Despite what the docs suggest, having the `.irbrc` file in my project's root folder did nothing.  It does work when in my home directory though.

Answer (score 39):

We can pass the `--noautocomplete` [command line option](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Command+line+options) when invoking IRB.

```
irb --noautocomplete
```

Alternatively we can set a [configuration option](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration) in `~/.irbrc` or one of the other locations specified in the documentation

```
IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

Starting a Rails console will respect this configuration but for a one-off we can provide the command line option.
Be sure to pass any Rails options before the `--`

```
rails console --sandbox -- --noautocomplete
```

Answer (score 13):

If you using IRB remotely and do not have permission to update `.irbrc` file, try this:

```rb
Reline.autocompletion = IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

This assignment changes the behaviour of the current session.

*May the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/irb/input-method.rb#L293) be with you*.