# Disabling irb autocomplete on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, irb

A follow up to [Disable irb autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70505085/disable-irb-autocomplete)

I would like to disable IRB on Heroku, e.g. having an `.irbrc` with:

```
IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

In the home directory of my heroku dyno/server

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your application's root directory ends up being the application's user's home directory at Heroku so you could put a `.irbrc` in your application's root directory. So add your `.irbrc` with `IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false` to your app's root directory so that it looks like this:

```
$ cd your_app_root_directory
$ ls -1A
.git/
...
.irbrc # <-----------------
...
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
Procfile
README.md
Rakefile
app/
bin/
config/
config.ru
db/
...
```

Then, once you push everything up to Heroku, `heroku run console` will use that `.irbrc`.

Comment: It works! Actually I had tried that but didn't get it pushed to heroku yet

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to update the `.irbrc` on Heroku because that would affect others' usage of it, you can also disable autocomplete on Heroku just for yourself via the command line when you open it. The quotes are critical, or you will get a `Thor::InvocationError`:

`heroku run "rails console -- --noautocomplete"`

Comment: The `heroku run` version is not working for me, I'm still getting the autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

Create an `.irbrc` file with this content:

```rb
IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
```