# Remove ruby 3.1 autocomplete feature for heroku console

Tags: ruby, heroku, irb, ruby-3.1

The *autocomplete* feature from Ruby 3.1 is really nice on local environment but makes the one-off Heroku dyno really slow. How could I remove the *autocompletion* with an `.irbrc` file?

I tried something like

```rb
# .irbrc

require 'irb/completion'

IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

but it seems not reading the `.irbrc` file.

I saw also that *irb* can take a `--noautocomplete` argument but I didn't manage to pass it to `rails c`

Comment: Same as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70768140/479863

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate