# How to disable Pry autocomplete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry, pry-rails

I would like to disable autocomplete in Pry. How to do it?

I'm using it in Rails console(from Emacs/inf-ruby) and it is very slow and annoying in my legacy app.

Related question: [Disable irb autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70505085/disable-irb-autocomplete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your `.pryrc` config file:

```ruby
Pry.config.completer = nil
```

Default value is `Pry::InputCompleter`

Or you can just launch your console with <kbd>--noautocomplete</kbd> option.

[Source @ github.com](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/db856653dd47995c39711f1518ebf94792e9c471/lib/pry/config.rb#L203)